# glDrawElements with constant normal

Tags: c++, opengl, constants, draw, normals

I was just curious if you can specify constant normal when drawing with single call of DrawElements. I'm using VAOs and VBOs so it's not that problem because I load them once for all vertices and just store VBO ID, but I could free some memory in graphic card..

this is the way you need to load data into graphics:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,VBO[Grid][Normals]);
glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, sizeof(vector3f), 0);
glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
```

As I specify some 5x5x5 grid and then use indices to create cubic surphace, it's not much to deal with normals and using some constant would help :)

Comment: What kind of hardware are you targeting? Any reason not to use a vertex shader which gets the normal as uniform input (or has the normal hardcoded)?

Comment: Please always specify your target OpenGL version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implementing the function using a vertex shader which specify always the same normal.  So, it's only required to specify the normal as uniform, since it's the same for those vertices.

Comment: Yeah that should do I am now using fixed pipeline because I'm not already in stage where I need to use shaders, but maybe it will be easier just to throw that code for loading shaders there and create simple shader...

Comment: Yes, there is a little effort before starting with shaders, but they allow you to implement the best algorithm without working around because the fixed pipeline implementation.

Comment: Even without having to work around fixed pipeline limitations, once you start using several fixed pipeline functions together it's propably easier with shaders.